# StealJS error: Cross origin requests are not supported for protocol schemes

Tags: cross-domain, canjs, stealjs

I am having an error like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/mshin/workspace/spirent/trinity/trinity-link/public/node_modules/can/view/stache/system.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

home.js:

```
import can from 'can';
import template from './home.stache!';

export default can.Component.extend({
  tag: 'home',
  template: template
});
```

The build config in Gruntfile:

```
"steal-build": {
  default: {
    options: {
      system: {
        config: "package.json!npm",
        bundlesPath: "production"
      },
      buildOptions: {
        minify: true,
        sourceMaps: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why I am getting this error message in production mode. In development environment, it works fine. Also, it is fine on test environment. I am running QUnit test with testee.

home_test.js:

```
import QUnit from 'steal-qunit';
import ViewModel from 'components/home/home';
import can from 'can';
import stache from 'can/view/stache/';
import $ from 'jquery';

var template = can.stache('<home></home>'),
    $component;

QUnit.module('home component', {
  setup: function() {
    $('#trinity-js-tests').html(template());
    $component = $('#trinity-js-tests').find('home');
  }
});

QUnit.test('title tag', function() {
  QUnit.ok($component.find('h1'), 'Page shows title with <h1> tag');
});

QUnit.test('title content', function() {
  QUnit.strictEqual($component.find('h1').text(), 'This is homepage.', 'Title is "This is homepage."');
});
```

However, if I change the home.js to like this:

```
import can from 'can';

export default can.Component.extend({
  tag: 'home',
  template: can.view('components/home/home.stache)
});
```

It works fine in production and development environment, but in test the last test case fails.

```
1) QUnit "public/tests/test.html" on PhantomJS 1.9.8 / Mac OS X 0.0.0: <a href="http://localhost:3996/public/tests/test.html?__token=k8l88m"></a>  home component title content Title is "This is homepage.":
     Error: Expected This is homepage. but was
      at http://localhost:3996/public/tests/test.html?__token=k8l88m:1340
      at http://localhost:3996/public/tests/test.html?__token=k8l88m:1907
      at :33
      at http://localhost:3996/public/tests/test.html?__token=k8l88m:895
      at http://localhost:3996/public/tests/test.html?__token=k8l88m:1024
      at process (http://localhost:3996/public/tests/test.html?__token=k8l88m:583)
      at begin (http://localhost:3996/public/tests/test.html?__token=k8l88m:628)
      at http://localhost:3996/public/tests/test.html?__token=k8l88m:644
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are loading it from the file:// protocol, is that correct? If so that's likely your problem.

Comment: Then, how I can load file with 'http' protocol in production mode?

Comment: I don't know why `can/view/stache/system.js` loaded by file:// protocol, not with dirname of the application.....

Comment: I find the reason and solution. I didn't import `can/view/stache/system.js` file in main file. I though `can/view/stache/stache.js` file import all the things, but it doesn't. So I added `import 'can/view/stache/system';` to the main javascript file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I missed in the code.

main.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import _ from 'lodash';
import stache from 'can/view/stache/';
import can from 'can';
import 'components/route/';
import 'less/trinity.less!';
```

I didn't import `can/view/stache/system` in it.
To use system plugin in `can.stache`, I need to import the specific file to main javascript file.

So, the file should be

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import _ from 'lodash';
import stache from 'can/view/stache/';
import 'can/view/stache/system';   // this is the added line
import can from 'can';
import 'components/route/';
import 'less/trinity.less!';
```